# count equal adjacent values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

i'm looking for a function to count the adjacent elements of an array.
here an example:

```
Array(A,A,A,B,B,C,A,A,A,C,C…)
```

function should return:

```
3*A, 2*B, 1*C, 3*A, 2*C,...
```

Do you know any function like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Without warnings,

```
    <?

function arrayCountAdjacent($array) {
    $adjacentArray = array();
    $lastValue = null;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($lastValue === null || $lastValue != $value) {
            $i++;
            $adjacentArray[$i] = array("value" => $value, "count" => 1);

            $lastValue = $value;
        }
        else {
            $adjacentArray[$i]["count"]++;
        }
    }

    return $adjacentArray;
}

$array = array("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C");
var_dump(arrayCountAdjacent($array));

foreach(arrayCountAdjacent($array) as $result)
{
    echo $result['count'] ."*". $result['value']."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
And thank you for reading my question so accurately. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, no notices/warnings.

```
$data = array("A","A","A","B","B","C","A","A","A","C");
foreach($data as $val){
    if(!isset($newarray[$val])){$newarray[$val]=0;}
    $newarray[$val]++;
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Outputs

```
Array ( [A] => 6 [B] => 2 [C] => 2 )
```

Or

```
$data = array("A","A","A","B","B","C","A","A","A","C");
foreach($data as $val){
    if(!isset($newarray[$val])){$newarray[$val]=0;}
    $newarray[$val]++;
}

foreach($newarray as $key=>$val){
    echo $val.'*'.$key.', ';
}
```

Outputs

```
6*A, 2*B, 2*C,
```

That should work fine ;)

Dom

Comment: Um, think it should be `$newarray[$val]++` instead of `$key` .. it's a numerical array ;) .. (and I didn't down vote) and change the function name to something like `array_count_values`, because [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is already a built-in function of PHP

Comment: this gives a syntax error (you can not just redeclare a system function), if that is solved, gives a bunch of warnings and outputs Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 )

Comment: Fixed it now, included the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('A','A','A','B','B','C','A','A','A','C','C');

$counts = array_reduce(
    array_keys($myArray),
    function (&$counter, $key) use ($myArray) {
        static $last = -1;

        if (($key > 0)  && ($myArray[$key] == $myArray[$key-1])) {
            list($char, $count) = explode('*',$counter[$last]);
            $counter[$last] = $char . '*' . ++$count;
        } else {
            $counter[++$last] = $myArray[$key] . '*1';
        }
        return $counter;
    },
    array()
);

var_dump($counts);
```